# Warning: [antd: Checkbox] `value` is not validate prop, do you mean `checked`?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using `antd` design with Reactjs. Found this warning but could not trace the issue.

Following code:

```
<Form.Item>
  {getFieldDecorator('order_receiver', {
      defaultChecked: true,
      rules: [
          {
              required: false,
              message:
                  'Offer!',
          },
      ],
  })(
      <Checkbox className="ps-checkbox">Order Receiver</Checkbox>,
  )}
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `valuePropName="checked"` in `getFieldDecorator` instead.

```html
<Form.Item name="checkbox">
  {getFieldDecorator('order_receiver', {
      defaultChecked: true,
      rules: [
          {
              required: false,
              message:
                  'Offer!',
          },
      ],
      valuePropName:"checked"
  })(
      <Checkbox className="ps-checkbox">Order Receiver</Checkbox>,
  )}
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `valuePropName` prop on the FormItem like below for remove this warning.

```
<Form.Item name="checkbox" valuePropName="checked">
  {getFieldDecorator('order_receiver', {
      defaultChecked: true,
      rules: [
          {
              required: false,
              message:
                  'Offer!',
          },
      ],
  })(
      <Checkbox className="ps-checkbox">Order Receiver</Checkbox>,
  )}
</Form.Item>
```